# Add swap support to Android

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, ram, lineageos, 7.1-nougat, swap

I own Samsung Galaxy GT-i9082, Trust me, its really very slow due to its low RAM i.e 1GB only. I have Installed Custom ROM of Lineage OS From XDA but it still doesn't supports swapping which is the only way to increase my SMARTphone's RAM. How can I add Swap support to my Kernel? I am really a new born baby in android and don't know much about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap in Android requires special kernel support... to my knowledge there is no stock based custom kernel pre-built with swap support for your device. You can see if your kernel, or any kernel for that matter, has swap support by opening a terminal (via Termux or other terminal application) and entering the following command:

`cat /proc/cpuinfo`

And look at the Features line in the output for `swp` or `swap`, if one of those occurs and you are rooted, then you maybe able to use swap space. - [Source](https://www.droidviews.com/speed-up-android-devices-using-swap-part-1/)

Building a kernel yourself with this support is outside the scope of Android Authority, if you wish to pursue this option I would suggest using a dedicated forum for this type of thing such as [XDA's Galaxy Grand Duos Development forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-grand-duos/development/) for more information.

That said, there is one custom ROM I am aware of which has swap support built in called Viper OS, more information on this ROM is available in it's [official support thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-grand-duos/development/rom-viper-os-v2-1-t3772380) on XDA Developers.

Be aware there are custom kernels that support zRAM, or compressed RAM, which might be sufficient for your needs... They increase usable RAM by using the kernel to compress the data it stores in RAM at the cost of some performance and battery life, the amount of benefit or performance/battery loss is purely based on your individual usage. [Grephene](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-grand-duos/development/kernel-graphenekernel-nougat-7-0-7-1-t3630991) and [DedS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2783310) kernel are available for your device which support zRAM. For more information on zRAM and it's potential benefits and issues, please see [What is zRAM in kernel](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2320734) and [Z-RAM, do you use it?](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1752079) threads on XDA or see Google for more information.

Comment: *"The SWP instruction was deprecated in the ARMv6 architecture, superseded
by the LDREX/STREX family of instructions"*. But kernel can still be built with CONFIG_SWAP. So the condition `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E 'swp|swap'` isn't always true.